# Search multi-dimesional array and return specific value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hard to phrase my question, but here goes. I've got a string like so: "13,4,3|65,1,1|27,3,2". The first value of each sub group (ex. **13**,4,3) is an id from a row in a database table, and the other numbers are values I use to do other things.

Thanks to "Always Sunny" on here, I'm able to convert it to a multi-dimensional array using this code:

```
$data = '13,4,3|65,1,1|27,3,2';

$return_2d_array = array_map (
  function ($_) {return explode (',', $_);},
  explode ('|', $data)
);
```

I'm able to return any value using

```
echo $return_2d_array[1][0];
```

But what I need to be able to do now is search all the first values of the array and find a specific one and return one of the other value in i'ts group. For example, I need to find "27" as a first value, then output it's 2nd value in a variable (3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run one more `foreach` loop like this:

```
$value_to_search = 27;
foreach($return_2d_array as $array){ 
    if($array[0] == $value_to_search){ 
        echo $array[1];  // will give 3
        break; 
    } 
}
```

Here's the [**live demo**](https://eval.in/658816).

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through the dataset building an array that you can use to search:

```
$data = '13,4,3|65,1,1|27,3,2';
$data_explode = explode("|",$data); // make array with comma values

foreach($data_explode as $data_set){
    $data_set_explode = explode(",",$data_set); // make an array for the comma values
    $new_key = $data_set_explode[0]; // assign the key
    unset($data_set_explode[0]); // now unset the key so it's not a value..
    $remaining_vals = array_values($data_set_explode); // use array_values to reset the keys
    $my_data[$new_key] = $remaining_vals; // the array!
}

if(isset($my_data[13])){ // if the array key exists
    echo $my_data[13][0];
    // echo $my_data[13][1]; 
    // woohoo!
}
```

Here it is in action: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/404ba5adfd63c39daae094f0b92e32ea0efbe85d

Comment: This is the method that you *should* use. PHP can much more efficiently access the data if you key the array on the IDs than you can by simply iterating through the array in the currently accepted answer.